# take subset from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

i'm planning to take a subset from a dataframe.

| A | B | C | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | chair |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | table |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | table |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | chair |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | drawer |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | drawer |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | chair |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | table |

i know the first step is to group by the dataframe based on the label. Then i want to take a subset of row with only label "chair", "chair & table", "chair & table & drawer" and put it into a new dataframe (there will be 3 separate dataframe in the end).
Is it possible to do this if i turn the data into numpy array and separate the label?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can simply select the required rows of your DataFrame like so:

```
df1 = df[df["Label"]=="chair"]
df2 = df[df["Label"].isin(["chair", "table"])]
df3 = df[df["Label"].isin(["chair", "table", "drawer"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  a dictionary with boolean indexing here which should solve it dynamically:

```
u = df['Label'].unique()
l = [u[:e+1] for e in range(len(u))]
d = {' & '.join(i):df[df['Label'].isin(i)] for i in l}
```

---

```
print(d['chair'],'\n------\n',d['chair & table'],'\n------\n',d['chair & table & drawer'])

 A  B  C  Label
0  3  2  3  chair
3  2  4  5  chair
6  3  2  3  chair 
------
    A  B  C  Label
0  3  2  3  chair
1  2  4  5  table
2  3  2  3  table
3  2  4  5  chair
6  3  2  3  chair
7  2  4  5  table 
------
    A  B  C   Label
0  3  2  3   chair
1  2  4  5   table
2  3  2  3   table
3  2  4  5   chair
4  3  2  3  drawer
5  2  4  5  drawer
6  3  2  3   chair
7  2  4  5   table
```